# fixed responsive container in bootstrap with horizontal menu items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="leftclass" style="float:left">
<div class="topbar">
 menu1  menu2  menu3  menu4
</div>
<div class="bottombar">
 menu5  menu6  menu7  menu8
</div>
</div>
<div class="rightclass" style="float:right">
<table class="table responsive">
<tr><td>info1</td><td>link1</td></tr>
<tr><td>info2</td><td>button2</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
  
</div>
```

I want to have responsive container with left side - two bars(one below other) containing menu-items and right side - table with some info and button-links.

Moreover I want this container to be fixed positioning and responsive for zooming in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You could be better off building the foundations of your site with the Bootstrap **Grid System**. It's very flexible and will most likely get you most of the way there.

[Check out the examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).